# How to use Symfony framework with Mercurial?

Tags: php, mercurial, symfony1

I'm starting to use the Symfony php framework.

Where can I find information about the use of Mercurial in my symfony projects?

Comment: Mercurial is in no way specific to Symfony. You use it just like you would on any other project...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things you need to keep in mind:

First: Put an .hgignore file in the root folder of your project. Put the following content in this file:

```
.project
^cache$
^log$
web/uploads
nbproject
```

nbproject is only needed if you are working with netbeans.

Second: At the moment there is no mercurial repository for Symfony itself, so you can not use the framework as a subrepository at the moment (BTW: I'm planning to setup one on bitbucket in the next days). So if you are using Symfony with svn:external at the moment you need to put a complete copy in the lib/vendor/symfony folder

Thats it :-)

Comment: I'm new to both Mercurial & Symfony, so please take this with a pinch of salt, but as of Mercurial 1.5 you can have a subrepository based on subversion - follow the instructions at http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Subrepositories#line-43 , using `lib/vendor/symfony = [svn]http://svn.symfony-project.com/branches/1.4` for your .hgsub file - I would however be interested to see a BitBucket repository provided it's kept up to date.